# How to make tags children unique?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

How to prohibit duplicate tag in my restriction tag in my xml file?
for example in my xml file I have two locale tag,but it should be only one tag

this is my xml file :

```
    <app:string name="firstName">
        <app:restriction>
            <app:regex>^\w*$</app:regex>
            <app:type/>
            <app:locale/>
            <app:locale/>
        </app:restriction>
    </app:string>
```

and this is my xsd for string tag:

```
<xs:element name="string">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="main:BaseType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="restriction" type="main:StringRestriction" minOccurs="0"
                                maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="lang" type="main:LocaleTypes"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="BaseType">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="main:nameType" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="readonly" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="true"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="StringRestriction">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="main:RestrictionBase">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="locale"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="type"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="regex"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="maxLen"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="minLen"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood you need a schema that force your `restriction` tag to contain tags without repetitions.

if you substitute this:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="locale"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="type"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="regex"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="maxLen"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="minLen"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
```

with this:

```
<xs:all minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="locale"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="type"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="regex"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="maxLen"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="minLen"/>
</xs:all>
```

your schema won't allow duplicated `locale` elements inside your `restriction` tag.
You can see a summary here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp
Beside this, you can play with `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` to force some elementes to always appear and other to be just optional.

Comment: sequence is a sorted list,but I need an unsorted list.so I used sequence with choice

Comment: In this case you can substitute the xsd:sequence element with the xsd:all element. xsd:all specifies that the child elements can appear in any order and that each child element can occur zero or one time.

Comment: I edited the answer changing the xsd:sequence tag with the xsd:all tag.